# grep variable pattern and output match and sequence position

Tags: bash, awk, grep, bioinformatics, fasta

Given the following string,

```
>Q07092
MWVSWAPGLWLLGLWATFGHGANTGAQCPPSQQEGLKLEHSSSLPANVTGFNLIHRLSLMKTSAIKKIRNPKGPLILRLGAAPVTQPTRRVFPRGLPEEFALVLTLLLKKHTHQKTWYLFQVTDANGYPQISLEVNSQERSLELRAQGQDGDFVSCIFPVPQLFDLRWHKLMLSVAGRVASVHVDCSSASSQPLGPRRPMRPVGHVFLGLDAEQGKPVSFDLQQVHIYCDPELVLEEGCCEILPAGCPPETSKARRDTQSNELIEINPQSEGKVYTRCFCLEEPQNSEVDAQLTGRISQKAERGAKVHQETAADECPPCVHGARDSNVTLAPSGPKGGKGERGLPGPPGSKGEKGARGNDCVRISPDAPLQCAEGPKGEKGESGALGPSGLPGSTGEKGQKGEKGDGGIKGVPGKPGRDGRPGEICVIGPKGQKGDPGFVGPEGLAGEPGPPGLPGPPGIGLPGTPGDPGGPPGPKGDKGSSGIPGKEGPGGKPGKPGVKGEKGDPCEVCPTLPEGFQNFVGLPGKPGPKGEPGDPVPARGDPGIQGIKGEKGEPCLSCSSVVGAQHLVSSTGASGDVGSPGFGLPGLPGRAGVPGLKGEKGNFGEAGPAGSPGPPGPVGPAGIKGAKGEPCEPCPALSNLQDGDVRVVALPGPSGEKGEPGPPGFGLPGKQGKAGERGLKGQKGDAGNPGDPGTPGTTGRPGLSGEPGVQGPAGPKGEKGDGCTACPSLQGTVTDMAGRPGQPGPKGEQGPEGVGRPGKPGQPGLPGVQGPPGLKGVQGEPGPPGRGVQGPQGEPGAPGLPGIQGLPGPRGPPGPTGEKGAQGSPGVKGATGPVGPPGASVSGPPGRDGQQGQTGLRGTPGEKGPRGEKGEPGECSCPSQGDLIFSGMPGAPGLWMGSSWQPGPQGPPGIPGPPGPPGVPGLQGVPGNNGLPGQPGLTAELGSLPIEQHLLKSICGDCVQGQRAHPGYLVEKGEKGDQGIPGVPGLDNCAQCFLSLERPRAEEARGDNSEGDPGCVGSPGLPGPPGLPGQRGEEGPPGMRGSPGPPGPIGPPGFPGAVGSPGLPGLQGERGLTGLTGDKGEPGPPGQPGYPGATGPPGLPGIKGERGYTGSAGEKGEPGPPGSEGLPGPPGPAGPRGERGPQGNSGEKGDQGFQGQPGFPGPPGPPGFPGKVGSPGPPGPQAEKGSEGIRGPSGLPGSPGPPGPPGIQGPAGLDGLDGKDGKPGLRGDPGPAGPPGLMGPPGFKGKTGHPGLPGPKGDCGKPGPPGSTGRPGAEGEPGAMGPQGRPGPPGHVGPPGPPGQPGPAGISAVGLKGDRGATGERGLAGLPGQPGPPGHPGPPGEPGTDGAAGKEGPPGKQGFYGPPGPKGDPGAAGQKGQAGEKGRAGMPGGPGKSGSMGPVGPPGPAGERGHPGAPGPSGSPGLPGVPGSMGDMVNYDEIKRFIRQEIIKMFDERMAYYTSRMQFPMEMAAAPGRPGPPGKDGAPGRPGAPGSPGLPGQIGREGRQGLPGVRGLPGTKGEKGDIGIGIAGENGLPGPPGPQGPPGYGKMGATGPMGQQGIPGIPGPPGPMGQPGKAGHCNPSDCFGAMPMEQQYPPMKTMKGPFG
```

I want to first grep for pattern matching 6 or more xGx repeats, where x is any character. This, I can easily do,

```
grep -EIho -B1 '([^G]G[^G]){6,}' file
```

which outputs

```
>Q07092
KGERGLPGPPGSKGEKGARGN
EGPKGEKGESGALGPSGLPGSTGEKGQKGEKGD
IGPKGQKGDPGFVGPEGLAGEPGPPGLPGPPGI
PGPKGDKGSSGIPGKEGP
FGLPGLPGRAGVPGLKGEKGNFGEAGPAGSPGPPGPVGPAGIKGAKGE
FGLPGKQGKAGERGLKGQKGDAGNPGDPGTPGTTGRPGLSGEPGVQGPAGPKGEKGD
AGRPGQPGPKGEQGPEGV
PGKPGQPGLPGVQGPPGLKGVQGEPGPPGR
QGPQGEPGAPGLPGIQGLPGPRGPPGPTGEKGAQGSPGVKGATGPVGPPGA
SGPPGRDGQQGQTGLRGTPGEKGPRGEKGEPGE
PGPQGPPGIPGPPGPPGVPGLQGVPGNNGLPGQPGL
EGDPGCVGSPGLPGPPGLPGQRGEEGPPGMRGSPGPPGPIGPPGFPGAVGSPGLPGLQGERGLTGLTGDKGEPGPPGQPGYPGATGPPGLPGIKGERGYTGSAGEKGEPGPPGSEGLPGPPGPAGPRGERGPQGNSGEKGDQGFQGQPGFPGPPGPPGFPGKVGSPGPPGP
KGSEGIRGPSGLPGSPGPPGPPGIQGPAGLDGLDGKDGKPGLRGDPGPAGPPGLMGPPGFKGKTGHPGLPGPKGDCGKPGPPGSTGRPGAEGEPGAMGPQGRPGPPGHVGPPGPPGQPGPAGI
VGLKGDRGATGERGLAGLPGQPGPPGHPGPPGEPGTDGAAGKEGPPGKQGFYGPPGPKGDPGAAGQKGQAGEKGRAGM
PGKSGSMGPVGPPGPAGERGHPGAPGPSGSPGLPGVPGSMGD
PGRPGPPGKDGAPGRPGAPGSPGLPGQIGREGRQGLPGVRGLPGTKGEKGDIGI
AGENGLPGPPGPQGPPGY
MGATGPMGQQGIPGIPGPPGPMGQPGKAGH
```

Now, I want to find the character position of all G's when they occur in 'TGA' or 'SGA'. The character positions should be based on the input and NOT the output.

Expected output,

```
$ some-grep-awk-code
>Q07092
TGA: 573
SGA: 384
```

The awk solution,

```
awk -v str='TGA' '{ off=0; while (pos=index(substr($0,off+1),str)) { printf("%d: %d\n", NR, pos+off); off+=length(str)+pos } }' file
```

outputs TGA both at character position 25 and 573.  However, I want to only identify the character position of G in SGA/TGA when they occur in the midst of six or more xGx repeats.

Really appreciate any help!

Comment: Shouldn't the matches be across multiple lines?

Comment: At the top of your question you say `6 or more xGx repeats` and at the bottom `six or more Gxx repeats`. Please [edit] your question to be consistent.

Comment: In the sample there no `TGA` that's inside `([^G]G[^G]){6,}`

Comment: @Fravadona, not sure but for lines starting from `>` IMHO at least I don't see OP needed TGA, SGA there but yes OP could confirm this thing once, cheers.

Comment: @Fravadona: The intent is find TGA/SGA in the input. The first grep is just to demonstrate that the search is restricted to six repeats of xGx.

Comment: @Faravadona: There is a single TGA in TGASGDVGSPGFGLPGLP

Comment: @Jalan the `GFG` doesn't match the regex

Comment: @Fravadona: You are right. Apologies. I should have better planned the obfuscation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a basic `awk` solution:

- Each sequence must span a **single line**
- The resulting positions are relatives to the start of the line

The algorithm first searches the parts of the line that match `[^G]G[^G]{6,}`, then searches for the occurrences of `SGA` and `TGA` in those parts. The implementation is a little tedious, as there's no `offset` option for the `match()` and `index()` functions of `awk`.

```bash
awk '
    BEGIN {
        regexp = "([^G]G[^G]){6,}"
        search["SGA"]
        search["TGA"]
    }
    /^>/ {
        print
        next
    }
    {
        i0 = 1
        s0 = $0
        while ( match( s0, regexp ) ) {
            head = substr(s0,RSTART,RLENGTH)
            tail = substr(s0,RSTART+RLENGTH)
            i0 += RSTART - 1
            for (s in search) {
                s1 = head
                i1 = i0
                while ( i = index(s1, s) ) {
                    s1 = substr(s1, i+1)
                    i1 += i
                    search[s] =  search[s] " " i1-1
                }
            }
            s0 = tail
            i0 += RLENGTH
        }
        for (s in search) {
            print s ":" search[s]
            search[s] = ""
        }
    }
'
```

---

###### Example with simplified sequences

```
>TEST1
SGA.G..G.TGATGA.G..G..G.SGA.....TGA.....SGA.....G..G.SGA.G..G..G.
>TEST2
.G..G.TGA.G..G.G.....G..G..G..G.SGA.G.
```

```
>TEST1
SGA: 1 25 54
TGA: 10 13
>TEST2
SGA: 33
TGA:
```

---

###### TODO

- Parameterize the regex and the search strings: it's not difficult per se but the current code will run into an infinite loop when a search string is empty or when the regex allows 0-length matches; you'll need to prevent that from happening.
- Allow multi-line sequences
- Allow overlapping matches for the regex. Basically, it means to look for the next match at `RSTART+1` of the previous iteration; that will generate a lot of duplicate results that you need to discard one way or an other.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried it on my one liner sequence file shown above. The output is 
```
>Q07092
SGA: 383
TGA:
```
For some reason, TGA is excluded.

Comment: I gave the answer to that on the comment above; there's a `GFG` in that sequence so it doesn't match `([^G]G[^G]){6,}`

Comment: That works like a charm. Problem solved. Just one more request. It would help immensely if you could describe the code a bit for posterity.

Comment: For example, I didn't know that awk takes regexp ([^G]G[^G]){6,} like grep.

Comment: @Jalan I updated the code, it can now process a file with multiple sequences in it. See the TODO list for the limitations of the current code

Comment: @Fravadona, ++ve for nice code. May be its early morning here, so requesting :) so first thing I got is I need to get all occurrences of search(which I will tweak in my code) and then we can have string `SGA/TGA` also? OR am I missing something here, cheers.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 OP's searching for the `SGA` and `TGA` that are inside the parts that match `([^G]G[^G]){6,}`

Comment: @Fravadona, Thanks for letting know. For regex `([^G]G[^G]){6,}` means like `SGTSGTTGT` something like that(because regex checks 6 or more occurrences)? And if its below than 6 eg: `STGA` it shouldn't print it, that's where I am confuse as of now.

Comment: @Fravadona, ok sorry but somehow its still not clear to me(your code is good nothing on it only on logic part), so in line `SGA.G..G.TGATGA.G..G..G.SGA.....TGA.....SGA.....G..G.SGA.G..G..G.` why 3rd SGA is not there in output but 1st SGA is there both are 3 in length only, sorry if I am bugging, just want to understand it, thank you.

Comment: the third SGA isn’t **inside** of a `([^G]G[^G]){6,}` match

Comment: @Fravadona: Thanks for the updated code and the TODO pointers. The code works flawlessly. I am new to coding so will take some effort to wrap my around the code.

Answer (score 4):

You could match all occurrences of the regular expression `[ST]GA` and look at the wider substring surrounding each match to compare that window to `(.G.){6}`. Here is some code to do that:

```
$ awk '
/^>/ { label = $0 ORS; next }
{
    while (match(substr($0, pos + 1), /[ST]GA/)) {
        pos += RSTART
        if (len = RLENGTH) {
            wbeg = pos - 18 + len   # 18 is the length of .G..G..G..G..G..G.
            wlen = 2 * 18 - len + (wbeg < 1 ? wbeg - 1 : 0)
            wbeg = (wbeg < 1 ? 1 : wbeg)    # substr must start from at least 1
            window = substr($0, wbeg, wlen)
            if (window ~ /.G..G..G..G..G..G./) {
                str = substr($0, pos, len)
                print label str ":", pos + int(len / 2)
                label = ""
            }
            pos += len - 1
        }
        if (pos >= length($0)) {
            break
        }
    }
    pos = 0
}
' file
>Q07092
SGA: 384
```

The output only shows `SGA: 384` because that is the only portion of the example input that meets the requirement:

> I want to only identify the character position of G in SGA/TGA when they occur in the midst of six or more xGx repeats.

Comment: ++ve for nice code. Looks like I too tried very near to it. I tried checking with OP and Fravadona but didn't understand, what is the role of `G....G` OR {6] here. If you could explain me on that one, will be grateful to you, cheers.

Comment: Thanks @RavinderSingh13! I think it's something like `grep -Eo '(.G.){6,}' file | grep -o '[ST]GA'` but with a way of printing the positions from the input file. In this code the logic is flipped around by looking for the shorter regex first, then looking at the wider context to see if has those `G`s.

Answer (score 3):

With your shown samples please try following `awk` code. Written and tested in GNU `awk` should work in any POSIX `awk`. In this code we could pass how many strings/variables into the function and can get their ALL present index values in the line. Pass all the values needs to be searched into `awk` variable named `keyWords` and it will look for all those into the lines.

```bash
awk -v keyWords="SGA,TGA" '
BEGIN{
  num=split(keyWords,arr1,",")
  for(i=1;i<=num;i++){
     checkValues[arr1[i]]
  }
}
!/>/{
  start=diff=prev=""
  while(match($0,/(.G.){6,}/)){
     lineMatch=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)
     start+=(RSTART>1?RSTART-1:RSTART)
     diff=(start-prev)
     for(key in checkValues){
       if(ind=index(lineMatch,key)){
          print substr(lineMatch,ind,length(key)),(RSTART?RSTART-1:1)+ind+start+diff
       }
       prev=start
     }
     $0=substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)
   }
}
'  Input_file
```

***Output*** with shown samples will be as follows:

```
>Q07092
SGA: 384
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. It works but when I try it on other strings containing multiple instances of SGA/TGA, it only outputs the position of the first match not all. Sorry, if this was not clear from the question.

Comment: @Jalan, np, could you please explain it more, so you saying you need all occurrences of `SGA` OR `TGA` should be printed? Then you saying string could be in form of `SGA/TGA` also with multiple occurrences? Request you to please clarify a bit more and I can tweak the code then. Thank you.

Comment: @Jalan, Could you please do confirm me on my question, I can fix my code then, looks to me I am very close so please do explain me what's not working and concept of that 6 characters(how its related to matches, sorry I am not able to understand it).

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 OP's expected output in the question is wrong, there's no `TGA` that satisfy his constraints

Comment: @Fravadona, oh ok, so `([^G]G[^G]){6,}` means look for 6 characters OR more and then search SGA/TGA in it but again in input `SGA.G..G.TGATGA.G..G..G.SGA.....TGA.....SGA.....G..G.SGA.G..G..G.` why `....SGA.....` is not coming, I apologies but somehow that logic is not clicking to me :(

Comment: did you try `grep --color -E '([^G]G[^G]){6,}'`? The highlighted parts are the ones where you need to search for `SGA` and `TGA`

Comment: @RavinderSingh13: Sorry for the delay in responding. Weekend and all. I would like to first find out all instances of 6 contiguous xGx repeats. In these repeats, I would like to search for SGA or TGA and print their character positions based on the input. Does that make sense?

Comment: @Jalan, np, I have made changes in code, with shown samples it works fine, cheers.

Comment: @Fravadona: Just out of curiosity, is it possible to pass a file containing a list of regexp to the awk code posted above similar to the grep -f option?